# How to limit which commits get sent when performing git push?

Tags: git, git-push

I'd like to push some mature commits to remote, but exclude the most recent commits.

I've read the man page for git-push, but probably don't fully understand how to make use of the <refspec> parameter.

I should probably avoid this situation by creating a separate development branch from which I can do all my clean up (rebase squash/drop/edit/etc.) before bringing chunked commits into a branch that tracks the remote branch. I didn't have the foresight and now I have a bunch of "fragment" commits that I don't want to publish, but I need to push the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the ref for the commit you want to push. This can be anything commitish, for instance: `12d3f1`, `HEAD^`, etc.

Then, do this:

```
git push origin <commitish>:<branch>
```

This means take "commitish" and make the `<branch>` on `origin` point to this commit.

A `<branch>` is nothing but a pointer to some commit.

This will fail if the `<commitish>` commit doesn't have the current remote `<branch>` in it's history.

Comment: I already have the branch setup for tracking the proper remote so it would be nice if I didn't have to specify the branch name, but looks like I need to.

Comment: Since you're not pushing a branch, remote-tracking branches won't work for this, sorry.